# Iis the 'radeon' open-source driver (not fglrx) able to produce sound through HDMI in 11.10 (x64)?

Tags: sound, drivers, radeon, hdmi

Just wanted to know if the open drivers provided for the Radeon graphics card --specifically the Juniper Radeon HD 5700 card -- are able to send sound through HDMI.

I'm not able to do that, but I'm unsure if it's because I installed the proprietary drivers, and uninstalled them, or if the audio part of it doesn't work with the open driver.

Answer (score 1):

The driver should work fine - make sure you have changed the hardware output to the HDMI output in your sound settings.

[image: sound settings]

If the internal one is still highlighted then you will get no sound through HDMI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark, unfortunately, I still can't get sound out of it.
I think, when I uninstalled the fglrx driver maybe the sound part of it it's still installed somehow, because, in my outputs, I can see the Juniper HDMI Audio Driver, and I can even select it, but I can't hear a thing, not even the speaker test.
You can see a ![Screenshot](http://www.yorchnet.com/picture_library/AudioDriverProblem.png).
And I can be sure that the card and the TV are working right because I can hear it in windows.